# git annex, how to add git-sub directories

Tags: git, git-annex

I have a scenario where I am moving my entire filestructure to git-annex.

It contains my current projects, old project, media, personal items, and so on. As a result, it contains a lot of git repositories that I want to annex for historical reasons.

But, git annex ignores the files that are already checked in to git. Even when i use --force it keeps ignoring them. How can I add those files without deleting the .git folder?

---

Why do I want to do this?

I have a complete, well-organized folder structure of everything that is important to me. Right now I keep the ENTIRE folder on my laptop, with 2 backups to external HD's. This means that a lot of my HD's space is used up by files I really might need acces to once a year. Git annex would solve that issue by keeping track of those less-often-used files without things getting disorganized(and therefore eventually lost), so I can keep them at other locations. Feel free to suggest other tools that might fit my need.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround from user EvanDeaubl: https://git-annex.branchable.com/forum/Git_repos_in_git_annex__63__/

> I'm currently storing git repos inside of my annex by using a separated git dir, so that git doesn't detect the nested repository and balk at adding it. Doing a git clone or git init with a --separate-git-dir= argument puts what would normally be in .git in that directory, and creates a simple .git file in its place which references the separated git dir.
>
> When I'm not using the repo, I move the .git file out of the directory, and everything looks like regular files to git-annex. When I want to use it, I move it back in place, and any git operations inside the repo directory use the inner git repo itself.
>
> Another option I used for a while was to store bare repos in the annex, and doing checkouts from those repos.

Not exactly a solution, but it might be a workable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned other tools, I thought I'd share what I do with plain git:

I have an external drive where I keep my backups. I use rsync to keep it up to date with what is on my computer. I have a git repository at the root directory of the external drive and I never sync a source folder directly to the root directory, always to a subdirectory -- that way if a source folder is a git repository it won't conflict with the git repository at the root of the external drive. Since the files on my computer include git repositories, I have a script that follows these steps for any folder that I'm backing up:

1. rsync --delete src/ dst/
2. depth-first search of all git repositories in the destination directory (the directories that contain the .git subdirectories)
3. for each repository found, git add dst/path/to/repo/  (note the trailing slash)
4. finally, in the dst directory, git add . (dot)

The result is that I have a git repository that contains the current state of all my files, and I can look back in time as usual with the git history.  The git repositories are backed up too, but their state is separate from the git repository at the root of the backup drive. So whatever untracked, uncommitted files I had in any of my git repositories do get committed to the git repository at the root of the backup drive.

The git repositories in the backup drive (e.g. dst/path/to/repo/.git) are just the latest copies with no meta-history.